# Integrate TextAngular into an application already using AngularJS

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate TextAngular into my website.

I am already using AngularJs and UI Directives for other features and these work fine, but when I try to add TextAngular everything falls over and dies.

I register my modules at the top of a Javascript file, which is added after TextAngular and AngularJS are, and I have added code here for TextAngular:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
//The above works for ui directives, I added this
angular.module('myApp', ['textAngular']);
```

I have added a bundle for text angular:

```cs
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/textAngular").Include(
"~/Scripts/textAngular.js"));
```

And here is my code for the editor:

```html
<div ng-controller="wysiwygeditor" class="container app"">
    <h1>Editor</h1>
    <div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent"></div>
    <textarea ng-model="htmlcontent" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
    <div ng-bind-html="htmlcontent"></div>
    <div ta-bind="text" ng-model="htmlcontent"></div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="htmlcontent = orightml">Reset</button>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/textAngular")

<script type="text/javascript">
    function wysiwygeditor($scope) {
        $scope.orightml = '<h2>Try me!</h2>';
        $scope.htmlcontent = $scope.orightml;
    };
</script>
```

This is in a partial view, the _Layout page contains a lot of twitter bootstrap content.

Like I say, AngularJS and UI Directives are working great, but when I try to wire in TextAngular it just doesn't want to work.

The error I get in Chrome is a bit cryptic:

> Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe
>   context. errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$sce/unsafe
>       at localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:78:12
>       at htmlSanitizer localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:12162:13
>       at getTrusted localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:12329:16
>       at Object.sce.anonymous function [as getTrustedHtml] localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:13027:16
>       at Object.ngBindHtmlWatchAction [as fn] localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:16993:25
>       at Scope.$digest localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:11501:27
>       at Scope.$apply localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:11740:24
>       at localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:1297:15
>       at Object.invoke localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:3633:25
>       at doBootstrap localhost:25332/Scripts/angular.js:1295:14

What am I doing wrong here? If you need to see more code just leave a comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding 'textAngular-sanitize.js' file:
https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular#usage

This file was meant to replace 'angular-sanitize.js' in the projects where textAngular is used. 
This is because angular-sanitize.js (ngSanitize) is too strict to meet textAngular needs:
https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular#where-to-get-it
(there is a note of this)

Answer (score 0):

try to add ***ngSanitize*** as a dependency in your app.

here your have more information : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize